# PHP MySql Query Get Sum Per User

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have users with rating and I want to show the total amount of rating of each user. I have 2 tables: users and feedback. I have 4 users in USERS table. And in table FEEDBACK (consists of applicant_id and app_experience columns) I have the rating of each user. But, I have several ratings for each person.

```
  $sql4 = "
 SELECT SUM(app_experience) as app_experience
     , applicant_id 
  FROM feedback f
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id=f.applicant_id 
 GROUP 
    BY feedback.applicant_id
";
  $res4 = mysqli_query($db,$sql4) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

This is my output, but it prints only 2 users, because in table FEEDBACK 2 of the users do not have any feedback yet:

```
  foreach ($res4 as $row) 
  {
   echo "".$row['applicant_id']."----".$row['app_experience']."";
   echo "<br>";
  }
```

My question is how to output all 4 users and I want to show the total number of rating next to each user.

I am doing something like this, but I do not know where to add the foreach loop above in the code below. Do you have any ideas?:

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users";
 $res2 = mysqli_query($db,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($db));
 while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2))
 {
   $id = $row2['id'];
   $name = $row2['name'];
 }
```

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` and `COALESCE(SUM(app_experience), 0)`

Comment: Ok, but where should I put the foreach loop and while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to modify the below statement :

```
$sql4 = "SELECT SUM(app_experience) as app_experience, applicant_id FROM feedback INNER JOIN users ON users.id=feedback.applicant_id GROUP BY feedback.applicant_id";
```

to :

```
$sql4 = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(app_experience), 0) as app_experience, applicant_id FROM users LEFT JOIN feedback ON users.id=feedback.applicant_id GROUP BY users.id";
```

The `users LEFT JOIN feedback ...` clause will allow the query to return a row even for users who do not have a feedback yet.

The `COALESCE(SUM(app_experience), 0)` will evaluate to `0` when a user has no feedback yet.

With this solution you don't need to loop.

Comment: When I try that, it shows me only the users that have some rating. The other 2 users are missing. I used the left join, but it does not work. Do you have any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Could be caused by the "group by" clause, just edited my answer, would you please try again ?

Comment: Thank you. You solution works great. Thank you for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome @Kaloyan !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.*, (SELECT SUM(app_experience) FROM feedback WHERE applicant_id = users.id) as feedback FROM users
```

Selects all users and their feedback in a short SQL

Comment: It shows me all the users, but I am not able to add more data to it and show it on the page. For example, I want to show the applicant_id and username of the user. When should I put these columns?

Comment: if applicant _id is the same as users.id as in your code it's $row['id'] and $row['username'], that you get from the users table in the select of users.*

Answer (score 0):

As written, your query will not run.  The `GROUP BY` clause is referencing `feedback`, but that reference has been changed to `f` by the alias.

You appear to want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.id, SUM(f.app_experience) as app_experience
FROM feedback f LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = f.applicant_id 
GROUP BY u.id;
```

This will return a `NULL` value for `app_experience`.  If you want a value (such as `0`) use `COALESCE(SUM(f.app_experience), 0)`.